# Bugzilla change the url in link in email

Tags: bugzilla

How can i change the value of "urlbase" param globally in bugzilla ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are an administrator, it's under Administration > Parameters.

Comment: Change the urlbase parameter after logging in as an administrator

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem recently installing bugzilla3 on Ubuntu 10.04LTS

Rather than edit the `/usr/share/perl5/Bugzilla/Constants.pm` file, I saw that if the variable debian_webpath is set to the value of the environment variable **X_BUGZILLA_WEBPATH**.
If not set, then it defaults to `/bugzilla3/` .

Make sure that **mod_env** is enabled in your apache setup (a2enmod env).

Then in my apache configuration file (`/etc/apache/hosts-available/default`), I added lines

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ...
        SetEnv X_BUGZILLA_WEBPATH /bugzilla/ 
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Also logged in to bugzilla and set the **urlbase** in the section: Administration > Parameters.

```
urlbase = http://my-server-name/bugzilla/
```

Answer (score -1):

It didn't work well in Ubuntu 9.04, it still doesn't in Ubuntu 10.10.

1. Change the following line in /usr/share/perl5/Bugzilla/Constants.pm

   $overwritten_locations{'debian_webpath'} = '/your_url_prefix_here/';
2. /etc/apache2/conf.d/bugzilla3.conf
   Alias /your_url_prefix_here /usr/share/bugzilla3/web
3. sudo vi /etc/bugzilla3/params
   'urlbase' => 'http://your_domain.tld/your_url_prefix/'

maybe also you'll need to adjust /usr/share/bugzilla3/debian/params
(same as item #3 above)

Good luck! ;)